# multi line label bootstrap

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, label

I'm making a horizontal form with bootstrap 3 and for required input fields I'd like to add an asterisc after each label. Of course this isn't a problem, but for layout purposes I want to do two things:

1) if a label (question) in the form is so long that it causes a linebreak I want the second part of the label (on the 2nd line) to be outlined on the right side with the first line.

2) labels without asterisc should be in line with labels with a asterisc.

[See the image for an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do0ki.png)

Can anyone please explain how I can use bootstrap styling/layout to have the labels with/without asterisc display at the same position, even when labels are spread across twee lines of text?

```css
.form-group.required .control-label:after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
}
label {
  text-align: right; /* bootstrap styling is missing, but usually label is aligned right */
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="question1">This is a really long label that breaks and spreads</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="question1" id="question1" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="question1">Short label (required)</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="question1" id="question1" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-xs-4 control-label" for="question1">Short label (not required)</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="question1" id="question1" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```